# Is there a way to insert a huge number of values into MySql in intervals?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drupal, limit

I am currently importing a Drupal blog into Wordpress, and there are a lot of pages and blog posts to import.  When I run the query it says it doesn't have sufficient memory or crashes.  I can run the query piece by piece using `LIMIT`, but I'm wondering if there is some smarter way to do the equivalent.

Either by running a for loop to insert a certain number of values at a time, or a callback function to execute the query after the query has been executed... I'm not sure.  Is there already a "best practice" way to do this?

Comment: Try to export the database using separate `INSERT` statements, instead of one big one.

Comment: Are you running your insert via the MySQL command line client or using something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin. Does it matter?  Doesn't it accept the same MySQL statements?

Comment: If you have a big amount of data is better doing this via the MySQL command line, phpMYAdmin is limited by the memory assigned to PHP in your php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the script bigdump http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/. It does a staggered import of an sql file. I always use it for importing databases that are larger then my phpMyAdmin allows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wordpress 'wp_insert_post' function in your script, Wordpress will cache the $post objects, with memory limit issue if a lot of posts are created.

To avoid this problem, use : `wp_suspend_cache_addition(true);` 
at the beginning of your script, so that WP stops caching each post object